# Issue with deploying war into weblogic through command line

Tags: deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to redeploy the war through command line. I am trying this:

> java -classpath "C:/bea/weblogic12c/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/weblogic.jar" weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:7101 -user username -password password -upload -redeploy -name myapp -source myApp.war -targets myServer

But, It does not work and I am getting this error:

> [java] Target state: redeploy failed on Server myServer
>        [java] weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Applicationmyapp is a WAR file, but it contains > 1 component.

I dont want to undeploy and deploy again. Is there a way to deploy/redeploy without undeploy?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that the redeploy will work with only EAR files. For WAR files, I have always had to redeploy in two steps (undeploy and deploy separately) when using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Same error with weblogic.WSLT (the richer scripting tool) using here the command:

```
wls:/mydomain/serverConfig> redeploy ('myWebApplication')
```

...but if you supply an explicit **appPath** option on the redeploy command line, it works! e.g.

```
wls:/mydomain/serverConfig> redeploy ('myWebApplication', appPath='/wl/deploy/myWebApp-1.0.war')
```